# How to suppress display of password in Selenium RC window

Tags: perl, selenium, selenium-rc

I am writing some Selenium RC tests using the perl library WWW::Selenium. At the beginning of the test I need to login to a web form using my username and password.

I noticed that my password is displayed in the Selenium Remote Control "Command History" window as `type(password, secret)`.

Is there any way to suppress the display of the password? Maybe there is a command other than `type` I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no. You could go into the Selenium core and change it to show `*******` when it finds a field named password.

Beware though that this *could* make life difficult when debugging

Answer (score 0):

I guess we can do this using native methods support.

Think logically every native methods in selenium will be sent to the operating system not to the browser.
So if you use any of the native methods, the flow is like this:

```
Client Program ----> Selenium RC server ----> to the operating system (in Java this is done using Robot Class)
```

But all the other non-native methods flow is like this:

```
Client Program ----> Selenium RC server ----> to the Browser
```

So, the Command History window operates at the Browser level and the native methods will not reach there.

Here is the code:

```
selenium.focus("locator");
selenium.keyPressNative("key code"); // this will not be shown in command history
```

Here the key code is only for one character and if you want string (more than one character), we should rely on our client program to implement the logic.

I have given that code in my previous answers to other posts. If you need it personalised post our exact requirement so that I can give that code tailored to your need.

Comment: This almost works. I am using perl and WWW::Selenium. I prompt for the password at the command-line and store the password in a variable. I then use `key_press_native` to enter the password. But, after the script terminates my password appears as typed at the command-line making my password visible. This only happens when I use `key_press_native`.

Comment: I think the keys entered via `key_press_native` are being put into the type-ahead buffer. (I am running Windows in case it matters.)

Comment: I think the "type-ahead" issue is actually a failure of Firefox to get the focus, so when the `key_press_native` happens the key presses are going into my console window rather than Firefox.

Comment: could you please put the code here in case if you still have that issue.